# Backup data from failing drive on Mac OS X... while preserving hardlinks

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac, backup, file-transfer

Long story short - I've got ~200 GB of data to copy off a failing hard drive (mostly Library and Application files are broken, user data intact) and I want to copy any intact file after I've managed to boot into the OS X recovery system.

Now here's the problem: there are **lots** of hardlinks. Issuing `cp -rf src dest` led to a full 500GB backup drive with many duplicates but other files missing. The options don't look too nice... in OS X:

- `cp` doesn't have an option for preserving hardlinks
- `pax` doesn't support error handling with the necessary `-rw` flag
- `tar` and `cpio` don't support error handling at all

This leaves me with four tools less to backup my data without having hundreds of gigabytes in duplicates. Any ideas on how to backup my stuff in one command without duplicating lots of data?

Comment: Can you copy to a partition or a completely new drive?  or do you need to copy into a directory on a new drive.  If you can copy to a completely new drive, take a look at superduper.  If you can copy to a partition consider using the dd command.

Comment: rsync?  http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apple-osx-bsd-rsync-copy-hard-links/

Comment: @skarface I can't install software into OS X Recovery as far as I know. `dd` seems like an overkill (I only want to secure /Users, but even in this directory there are too many hardlinked files) and furthermore, how would I access the `dd` image in OS X and would I still be able to see which files have I/O errors in them? I have no use for broken files. But I'll give `rsync -a -H --progress SRC DEST` a try, thanks. (If it wasn't for your comment, I would've installed Ubuntu onto a flash drive and tried GNU `cp` which supports preserving hardlinks but hopefully, `rsync` will work.)

Comment: @skarface `rsync` isn't available in OS X Recovery. Then I'll just give Ubuntu a shot, I guess. Seems like too much trouble installing OS X on an external drive just to use Super Duper or CCC to perform a backup :/

Comment: @skarface so not my day - in Ubuntu, `cp` crashed with a segmentation fault... urgh.

Answer (score 2):

Never mind - copying the files using Ubuntu and GNU  `cp -a` turned out to work fine, although I had to make the backup volume a linux file system (I used ext3) since trying to copy onto an HFS+ backup volume using hfsprogs crashed `cp` with a segfault leading to a broken HFS+ backup volume and a `cp` process with couldn't be killed and made a reboot necessary... most likely a bug in hfsprogs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late here, but for the record: the recovery system doesn't include `rsync`, but you can run it from the main volume as `/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/usr/bin/rsync` (or whatever your main volume's named).

Another possibility would be to use Recovery to install OS X onto a flash drive (El Capitan is a little over 8GB, so 16G is probably enough), then run whatever tools you want from that. Or, for that matter, partition the disk you're recovering onto and install a temporary system on that.